# What is the modern equivalent of Soviet tire size 65-405 (2.50-16)?

Tags: motorcycle, tires, conversion

The title question says it all. My Goggle-Fu isn't strong enough to find any conversion charts. The only size-related markings on the current tires are `65-405 (2.50-16)`. I believe they are motorcycle or motorcycle-sidecar tires with a tube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm seeing, the 2.50-16 *is the current size*. Doesn't look like [there's a large selection out there](https://www.chapmoto.com/dept-2-50-16-tires/) but you can find them. They are shown as a front tire. A Google search for "motorcycle tire 2.50-16" gave me a pretty good list of things.

**EDIT:** To clarify, the 2.50-16 is 2.5" x 16". This is imperial sizing for the tire. Also, if your rim requires a tube for the tire, you can get a tubeless tire and still put a tube in it to keep the air in. Either kind of tire will work.

Comment: OK, I finally found them in local shops too. I think it was the rarity that threw me off, because I tried searching for that "2.50-16" and came up empty handed. Thanks!

Comment: A local shop just replied to me that they don't have the 16x2.5 that I ordered 3 weeks ago, but that they do have 16x1,75-2,1. It's close... do you think it would still work?

Comment: @Vilx- That'd be 30% skinnier tires. I mean, they'll fit, but that's a LOT smaller than stock. I wouldn't run them, but that's up to you.

Comment: OK, I'll keep looking. Thanks!